# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default') in release build

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have used react-navigation library for the bottom tab, everything is working fine in debug mode but when I release app is crashing with below exception -

```
[error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
    in r
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in n
    in t
    in t
    in RCTView
    in e
    in n
    in o
    in r
    in r
    in t
    in o
    in n
    in RCTView
    in e
    in a
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in t
2019-09-16 20:06:43.645 [error]
```

react-navigation library link - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

I am able to generate release build for android.

*** Dependencies ***

```
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "6.5.3",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.12.1",
```

Could you please suggest?